# Encoding issue when printing all files of a disk

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

When listing all files of a disk with:

```
import os
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('d:\\'):
    for name in files:
        fname = os.path.join(path, name)
        print 'hello %s' % fname
```

I get:

> [Decode error - output not utf-8]

With similar code I sometimes get:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 60: ordinal not in range(128)

**How to solve this?**

---

*Note: I'm using Python 2.7 with Windows 7. I have read many questions on SO about UTF-8 encoding, and have tried various things like:*

```
print name.encode('utf-8')  # or utf8
print name.decode('utf-8') 
print name.decode().encode(...)
```

*Of course `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in in my .py file.*

Comment: There are probably dirs or files in the path that aren't utf-8 encoded strings, so when you try to print them python doesn't know how to decode them.  I don't think it has anything to do with the coding of your .py file.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
import os, sys
enc = sys.getfilesystemencoding()

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('d:\\'):
    for name in files:
        fname = os.path.join(path, name).decode(enc)      # decode the inputs
        print fname.encode('utf8')                        # encode the outputs
```